# React Native --- Error: Cannot find native module 'ExpoFontLoader', js engine: hermes

Tags: react-native, expo

I installed :

```
   "expo": "^49.0.11",
    "expo-constants": "^14.4.2",
    "expo-font": "^11.6.0",
    "expo-modules-core": "^1.5.11",
```

But I still get the error.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I have the same problem and so far I only found you talking about it

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, although it's not a good one.

I lowered expo-font version from 11.6.0, to 10.0.4. I don't know if there's a newer version of expo-font that works, but 10.0.4 version works for me. The reason it's not a good solution is because it throws tons of warnings (like ~1500 warnings).

**Edit:**
Now I found out that version 10.0.4 doesn't work on Android, but it does on iOS. However if I use 11.6.0, then Android works, but iOS doesn't. If someone has better solution that this, please write it here.

**Solution:**
I use expo-font 10.2.1 version and in order to build Android, you have to downgrade gradle version from as written [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/23023#issuecomment-1614584412)!

Also, I don't know if this is necessary, but for iOS only I also followed instructions as written [here](https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/)!